# How to prevent angular from creating unit test file while generating component

Tags: unit-testing, angular-components

Is there any command line argument that will help generating angular component but not create unit tests file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docs the `nc generate component` command has a `--skip-tests` flag:

> Do not create "spec.ts" test files for the new component.

https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Example:

```
ng generate component MyComponent --skip-test
```